# why R function as.character automatically generates a line-break（ \n）when applied to a list？

Tags: r, string, list, debugging, line-breaks

UPDATES: It turns out that as.character has a 500 character "soft limitation" when coercing long string(list).

---

Hi everyone:

I have a long string list of a location set in R, which is:

```
a=c("CANADA", "UNITED.STATES", "VIETNAM", "TAIWAN", "RUSSIAN.FEDERATION", "SENEGAL", "SOUTH.AFRICA", "MALAWI", "SLOVENIA", "BELGIUM", "ISRAEL", "HONG.KONG", "FRANCE", "PHILIPPINES", "MYANMAR", "GERMANY", "UKRAINE", "CENTRAL.AFRICAN.REPUBLIC", "COTE.D.IVOIRE", "JAPAN", "ZAMBIA", "SOUTH.KOREA", "DEM.REP.OF.CONGO", "SPAIN", "SWEDEN", "BOTSWANA", "AUSTRALIA", "CHINA", "MALAYSIA", "PAKISTAN", "ITALY", "CAMEROON", "BRAZIL", "CUBA", "DENMARK", "UGANDA", "THAILAND", "CYPRUS", "GHANA", "TANZANIA", "KENYA","MONGOLIA", "INDIA")
```

But when I try to convert "list(a)" to a single string use as.character(in order to store it as a whole), the command is:

```
as.character(list(a))
```

Then, a `"\n"` is automatically created between location "KENYA" and "MONGOLIA", the output should look like:

```
[1] "list(c(\"CANADA\", \"UNITED.STATES\", \"VIETNAM\", \"TAIWAN\", \"RUSSIAN.FEDERATION\", \"SENEGAL\", \"SOUTH.AFRICA\", \"MALAWI\", \"SLOVENIA\", \"BELGIUM\", \"ISRAEL\", \"HONG.KONG\", \"FRANCE\", \"PHILIPPINES\", \"MYANMAR\", \"GERMANY\", \"UKRAINE\", \"CENTRAL.AFRICAN.REPUBLIC\", \"COTE.D.IVOIRE\", \"JAPAN\", \"ZAMBIA\", \"SOUTH.KOREA\", \"DEM.REP.OF.CONGO\", \"SPAIN\", \"SWEDEN\", \"BOTSWANA\", \"AUSTRALIA\", \"CHINA\", \"MALAYSIA\", \"PAKISTAN\", \"ITALY\", \"CAMEROON\", \"BRAZIL\", \"CUBA\", \"DENMARK\", \"UGANDA\", \"THAILAND\", \"CYPRUS\", \"GHANA\", \"TANZANIA\", \"KENYA\", \n\"MONGOLIA\", \"INDIA\"))"
```

Notice the `"\n"` inserted, and when I deleted first element(CANADA), the `"\n"` moved to between "TANZANIA", "KENYA", so it looks like `"\n"` is always created before the 42nd element.

However, when I create a sequential number of string, that is, `a=c("1","2"..."41","42","43")`, do the same convertion `"as.character(list(a))"`,

No `"\n"` is created!

I'm confused, anyone know why?

Comment: Note
as.character breaks lines in language objects at 500 characters, and inserts newlines. Prior to 2.15.0 lines were truncated.

Comment: You probably want to use, `paste` with *collapse* arg: `paste(a, collapse=" ")`.

Comment: Yes, I found that note in function documentation too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are coercing a `list` object into a character string. If you want to convert into a single string, try (as @Parfait suggested):

```
paste0(a, collapse = ",")
```

If you don't want a comma-delimited string, then change the value in the `collapse` argument.